# Convert collection of models into an array with id as key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using [Laravel HTML](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) component to create a dropdown to list all the groups to which an user can belong.

The list of groups comes from a Groups table.

Currently in my controller my code looks like

```
    $groups = array();
    $groupModels = Group::all(['id', 'name']);

    foreach ($groupModels as $groupModel) {
        $groups[$groupModel->id] = $groupModel->name;
    }

    return view('myview', compact('groups'));
```

and in my view I have the following code to create the dropdown

```
    {!! Form::select('group', $groups, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

This works, but I am trying to see if there is a way to avoid the `foreach` loop and directly convert the list of Models into an array. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck()` method:

```
$groups = Group::pluck('name', 'id');
return view('myview', compact('groups'));
```